# Distance function on the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces, circles

Intuitively, The minor arc between two points on the circle is a distance function. I want to prove it. We define the four quadrant inverse tangent function Atan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) as
$$\operatorname{Atan}: \mathbb{C} -\{0\} \longrightarrow (- \pi, \pi], \quad
\operatorname{Atan}(a + i \, b) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \arctan (\frac{b}{a}) , & a > 0; \\[0.8ex]
    \arctan (\frac{b}{a}) + \pi , & a < 0  \text{ and } b \geq 0;\\[0.8ex]
    \arctan (\frac{b}{a}) - \pi , & a < 0 \text{ and } b < 0;\\[0.8ex]
    \operatorname{sign}(b) \, \frac{\pi}{2} , & a = 0 \text{ and } b \neq 0.
  \end{array}
\right.$$
and define the distance function $d: \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$d(z,w) = \min \big\{\lvert \operatorname{Atan}(z) -\operatorname{Atan}(w) \rvert ,
2\pi - \lvert \operatorname{Atan}(z) -\operatorname{Atan}(w) \rvert \big\}.$$
But I cannot prove the triangle inequality. I just can do it in the case
$$\lvert \operatorname{Atan}(z) -\operatorname{Atan}(w) \rvert + \lvert \operatorname{Atan}(w) -\operatorname{Atan}(v) \rvert \geq \lvert \operatorname{Atan}(z) -\operatorname{Atan}(v) \rvert \geq d(z,v). $$
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $e(z,w)=\operatorname{Atan}(z)-\operatorname{Atan}(w)$. Then $e(z,w)+e(w,u)+e(u,z)=0$. If all $|e(z,w)|$, $|e(w,u)|$, $|e(u,z)|$ are less or equal $\pi$, then $d(z,w)=|e(z,w)|=|-e(w,u)-e(u,z)|\leq |e(w,u)|+|e(u,z)|=d(w,u)+d(u,z)$. Other cases can be considered similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still only able to process this one case.

Comment: Second case. Let exactly one of $|e(z,w)|$, $|e(w,u)|$, $|e(u,z)|$ is greater than $\pi$. Let WLOG, that $|e(z,w)|>\pi$, $|e(w,u)|\leq \pi$, $|e(u,z)|\leq \pi|$. If $e(w,u)$ and $e(u,z)$ have opposite signs then $|e(z,w)|=|e(w,u)+e(u,z)| \leq \max(|e(w,u)|,|e(u,z)|) \leq \pi$. Then $e(w,u)$ and $e(u,z)$ must have the same sign. Then $|e(z,w)|=|e(w,u)|+|e(u,z)|$, then $d(z,w)=2\pi-|e(z,w)|<\pi<|e(z,w)|=d(w,u)+d(u,z)$. $d(z,w)+d(u,z)=2\pi-|e(z,w)|+|e(u,z)|=$ $2\pi-|e(w,u)|-|e(u,z)|+|e(u,z)|=2\pi-|e(w,u)|=2\pi-d(w,u)$. $d(w,u)=|e(w,u)|\leq \pi$, then $d(z,w)+d(u,z)\geq \pi \geq d(w,u)$.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help!